# Evaluate $\int_{\gamma} \left(\frac{\ 1}{z^2-1}\right) dz$ around the curve ${\gamma}(t)=2e^{it}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let  ${\gamma}(t)=2e^{it}$ for $-\pi\leq t\leq \pi$ and find
$$\int_{\gamma} \left(\frac{\ 1}{z^2-1}\right) dz.$$

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contour $\gamma$ encircles the poles at $z=\pm 1$.  Using the residue theorem, we have

$$\oint_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z^2-1}\,dz=2\pi i\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{-2}\right)=0$$

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $\gamma$ is just the circle of center $0$ and radius $2$. $z^2-1 = (z-1)(z+1)$. $-1$ and $+1$ lie in the interior of the circle. Simply apply [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula).

Comment: @AhmedHuseein  thank u so much

Comment: You're welcome.